# Export animation to FBX with paranting and without rigs

Tags: animation, rigging, parent, .fbx

I'm currently learning blender. I made a simple animation with several objects. Animated objects are parented, transforms are animated by using relative transforms (some kind of a very simple character).

[image]

I tried to export this animation file to FBX and then reimported it in Blender. It seems that the transforms of all objects are broken. As I understand, this is because I didn't apply transforms of my objects before exporting. But if I apply transforms my relative animations won't work.

I understand that the correct way to animate such "characters" is by rigging. But in theory is it possible to correctly export this animation to FBX?